# xamarin not showing in visual studio 2010 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin

I have installed xamarin 3.11.688. Xamarin is found inside the extensions folder but not in the visual studio 2010 ultimate IDE.Please help. I have tried

1. re installing xamarin
2. .devnev.exe/setup
3. .re installing visual studio.

Comment: Could you email Xamarin support with Visual Studio version information

Answer (score 0):

From the source - upgrade to VS2012 - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/

*Xamarin for Visual Studio supports any Visual Studio 2015 (Community, Professional, and Enterprise) and non-Express editions of Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 and Visual Studio 2012.*